# Showing a popup show what's behind

Tags: html, css, popup

When I show a popup, the circle used for decoration show up, I don't know how solve that,

Here's the fiddle :

```js
some code
https://jsfiddle.net/MagikMike/pctb9e0n/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give your circles IDs, in this case I added an ID circle0 and circle1 to both circles -

```
<div class="overlay" id="popup1"><div class="popup" id="popup"></div></div>

<div class="userMonitoringTarget">
  <div class="circle1" id="circle0">
    <div class="circle2">
      <div class="circle3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <div class="userMonitoring">
                <div>
                    <span>
                        Date : 00/00/0000
                    </span>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            LOREM IPSUM
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="userMonitoringAttachement">
                    <img src="/image/icon/icn-plus.svg" alt="+"
                    onclick="show_popup(' . $user->getNum() . ',' . $monitorings->id[$i] . ');return false;">    
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
<div class="userMonitoringTarget">
  <div id="circle1" class="circle1">
    <div class="circle2">
      <div class="circle3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <div class="userMonitoring">
                <div>
                    <span>
                        Date : 00/00/0000
                    </span>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            LOREM IPSUM
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="userMonitoringAttachement">
                    <img src="/image/icon/icn-plus.svg" alt="+"
                    onclick="show_popup(' . $user->getNum() . ',' . $monitorings->id[$i] . ');return false;">    
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

In your JS, your circles still showed because you didn't target them and set the visibility to hidden; now that we have IDs associated with the two circles you can properly get and set the visibility when the pop up is shown.

```
function hide_popup()
{
   setTimeout(function()
   {
       document.getElementById('popup1').style.visibility = "hidden";
       document.getElementById('popup1').style.opacity = 0;
       document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = "";
    }, 100);
}
function show_popup( user, monitoring )
{
    document.getElementById('circle0').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('circle1').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('popup1').style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('popup1').style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `z-index` for your popup wrapper like so.

```
#popup1 {
  z-index: 999;
}
```